# Print Statement is getting executed twice which is present before run method invoke in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Print Statement is getting executed **twice** which is present before run method invoke in Spring boot

*After run method invoke, one more print statement is present which is getting executed **once** as expected.*

[image]

It seems that control is hitting the main method twice but why not **later one** print statement is getting executed **twice**.

**Note** - I have dev-tools configure in pom.xml

Could someone help me to understand the flow behind that use case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is normal, if you have DevTools on your classpath. If you look at the Stack, you will see, that the second execution is under the hood of the RestartLauncher.

```
---------------- START ----------------
java.lang.Exception
    at de.solitics.overwatch.app.OverwatchApplication.main(OverwatchApplication.java:37)
---------------- START ----------------
java.lang.Exception
    at de.solitics.overwatch.app.OverwatchApplication.main(OverwatchApplication.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

Comment: how we could see these exception stack.?

Comment: Create a new Exception and call e.printStackTrace() or debug the application and set breakpoints at the entry of the main method